# Where is the bleachbit configuration file for root

Tags: 18.04, root, bleachbit

If I want to edit the bleachbit configuration file for the user, I access:

`.config/bleachbit/bleachbit.ini`

If i run bleachbit GUI as root, it has more options than if i run bleachbit as a user. I do not find these "extra" options in "bleachbit.ini".

Where is the bleachbit configuration file for root? (ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: It should be `/root/.config/bleachbit/bleachbit.ini ` I'm not sure...

Comment: I already tried it and it's not there

Comment: @Ravexina Surely you mean `/root/.config/bleachbit/bleachbit.ini`

Comment: @bdc If you run blechbit using `sudo` it should get created ...

Comment: The main configurations are the same, if you change some setting while you are running the program using `sudo` the content of root's config file should change.

Comment: If you run bleachbit GUI as root, it has more options than if you run bleachbit as a user. I do not find these options in "bleachbit.ini"

Comment: Does these new options already checked?  do they have any pre-configured settings? if not so their shouldn't be in config file too.

Comment: @Ravexina That is the solution. If I mark an extra option in bleachbit (root), change the file /root/.config/bleachbit/bleachbit.ini (but not /home/user/.config/bleachbit/bleachbit.ini) Thanks for your support

Comment: I'm glad that it worked ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config file for "root" user lives at:

```
/root/.config/bleachbit/bleachbit.ini
```

If it's not there the run the program using `sudo`, it should get created.